# Google Books API shows only 10 results. Want to iterate the startIndex so that it loops until all the results are shown

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

```
function bookSearch() {
  var search = document.getElementById('search').value
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = ""
  console.log(search)
  var startIndex =
```

So I want to iterate the ajax call until it shows all the items and not just the 10. Can get 40 by using `maxresults` parameter. So the startIndex needs to change from 0 to 20 to 40 to 60 and so on after every iteration.

```
while (startIndex < 2000) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + search + "&startIndex=" + startIndex + "&maxResults=40",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data)
      for (i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
        results.innerHTML += "<h2>" + data.items[i].volumeInfo.title + "</h2>"
        results.innerHTML += "<h2>" + data.items[i].volumeInfo.authors + "</h2>"
        results.innerHTML += "<h2>" + data.items[i].volumeInfo.publishedDate + "</h2>"
      }
    },
    type: 'GET'
  });
}
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', bookSearch, false)
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using . Look under the pagination section. If maxResults is not specified, the default is 10. Looks like you have to specify maxResults if you want more than the default.

Comment: instead of specifying it everytime, i want to add a loop where it keeps updating itself until all the results are shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. Count total_items until it reach more than 40 and loop the function to print the results:

```
// start

var startIndex=0;


// button clicked
$("#button").click(function(){
  $("#results").html('<img src="img/loader.gif" alt="" class="loader">');
  var searchInput = $("#search").val();
  getBooks(searchInput)
})


// onclick function run
function getBooks(search) {
  RunApi(search, startIndex);
  $("#results img").remove();
}

// run function to get results if available
function RunApi(search, start){
  $.ajax({
    url:"https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + search + "&maxResults=40&startIndex="+start,
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      totalItems = data.totalItems;
      if(data.items){
        for(i=0; i<data.items.length; i++){
          if(data.items[i].volumeInfo){
            var itemNubmer = startIndex+i;
            results.innerHTML += "<h2>"+itemNubmer+": " + data.items[i].volumeInfo.title + "</h2>"
            // results.innerHTML += "<h2>" + data.items[i].volumeInfo.authors + "</h2>"
            // results.innerHTML += "<h2>" + data.items[i].volumeInfo.publishedDate + "</h2>"
          }
          
        }
      }
      // repeat the function
      if(totalItems > 40){
      startIndex+=40;
      RunApi(search, startIndex);
      }
    },
    type:'GET'
  });
}
```